# How can I get the Values of a CheckBoxList Made through Below code in asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

I have Made the CheckboxList like this?

```
<%foreach(ListItem m in bootcamp.STPs.ProjectManagement.Controllers.MemberController.JALLMembers()){%>
  <label for=""><%= m.Text %></label>  
  <input id="Mana" type="checkbox" value="<%= m.Value %>" name="chkbx" />
<%}%>
```

How can I get the Values of selected checkboxes through ajax script in controller?

I am using Asp.net MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or serialize the form?

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  alert($(this).serialize());
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have find the answer

```
    var data2="";

    $("input[name=chkbx]").each(function()
    {
    if($(this).attr("checked")==true || $(this).val()==undefined)
    return false;
    data2 +=$(this).val() + ",";
    });
```

By this you can collect all selected checkboxes Values with comma seprated.